# Firestore: import sql database

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

Can't find any option to import my SQL Database into Firestore database.
Realtime Database has this function, for example.
Is it suggested to be available in Firestore after the Beta ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a direct import right now.

You have a few options though:

- Use the Firebase libraries to export data from your SQL application into Firestore manually (alternatively write a cloud function and get the data via an API). This can also be a good option, if you need to keep both DBs in sync for some transition time.
- If you need to get your user accounts over to Firebase Auth, read [this article](https://medium.com/@morgler/migrate-rails-devise-users-to-firebase-authentication-6f064628d358)
- If you already have your data in a Firestore, gcloud now has an import in beta (https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/export-import)

From your description I fear that the first option is the way to go for you. Unfortunately Firestore is still in beta and we have to create a lot of functionality ourselves (like SQL imports, data migrations, test mocks, …).